# Почему при запуске скрипта Питон в диспечере отображается как 32 бита?

Tags: python

почему при запуске скрипта Питон в диспетчере задач отображается как 32 бита? Хотя установлена версия 64-битная
В PATH вроде папку указал по дефолту, куда установился сам Питон место не менял
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну так посмотри откуда процесс запускается, что гадать-то

Comment: Если я правильно посмотрел, то по этой директории C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311

Comment: там два exe файла python.exe  и  pythonw.exe

Comment: запускается с этого  -  python.exe

Comment: а, так непонятно. Я думал, он в программах установлен, а не в папке пользователя.

Comment: Обьясните пожалуйста, это так и должно быть в диспечере? Дело в том что если запустить скрипт с кодом      import platform
                 print(platform.architecture())  то выводит что 64 бита, а деспечере 32. Мне просто для себя чтоб знать

Comment: Почему вы все время коверкаете слово "диспетчер"?) То "диспечер", то "деспечер")) Должно же вроде красным подчеркиваться?)